# kivy launcher crashes immediately, logcat filtering?

Tags: python, kivy, logcat

I'm trying to get an application that I made to run on my android phone. The application runs fine on my macbook. I've only used modules that are preinstalled with either python or kivy but still, the app crashes immediately after the loading icon appears on kivy launcher. So I did some digging and found that I can check the logs by unlocking developer options on my phone and using logcat but the problem is, logcat just spits out wayy to much information for me to parse through.

Is there a way to filter logcat to pull up the logs for the kivy launcher specifically? I've checked all over and everbody says you can filter it by app name but I've tried multiple variations of

adb logcat "application_or_tag_name:*" "*:S"

eg.:
adb logcat "Kivy_Launcher:*" "*:S"
adb logcat "kivy_launcher:*" "*:S"
adb logcat "Kivy Launcher:*" "*:S"

but none of them seem to work. I've read through these links:

https://logmatic.io/blog/a-how-to-guide-to-debugging-with-android-logcat/
https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat

I was able to get some of the logs via Android Studio but im not sure if these logs are for the "new app" that I had to create to launch the program, or if they are actually the logs from my phone when i launch kivy launcher. Here those are:

```
2019-03-12 01:49:32.213 4870-5048/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '8e355db org.kivy.pygame/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2019-03-12 01:55:17.347 32697-32697/? E/org.kivy.pygam: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2019-03-12 01:55:17.549 32697-32697/? E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/kivy/MyApp/icon.png (No such file or directory)
2019-03-12 01:55:18.968 4326-5050/? E/BufferQueueProducer: [org.kivy.pygame/org.renpy.android.ProjectChooser[32697]#0] disconnect: not connected (req=1)
2019-03-12 01:55:18.982 32733-32733/? E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/kivy/MyApp/icon.png (No such file or directory)
2019-03-12 01:55:19.833 4326-6594/? E/BufferQueueProducer: [org.kivy.pygame/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity[32733]#0] disconnect: not connected (req=1)
2019-03-12 01:55:20.873 4870-5048/? E/InputDispatcher: channel 'fda44c2 org.kivy.pygame/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2019-03-12 01:59:52.134 1975-1975/? E/org.kivy.pygam: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2019-03-12 01:59:52.325 1975-1975/? E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/kivy/MyApp/icon.png (No such file or directory)
2019-03-12 01:59:53.379 2044-2044/? E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/kivy/MyApp/icon.png (No such file or directory)
2019-03-12 01:59:53.421 4326-4361/? E/BufferQueueProducer: [org.kivy.pygame/org.renpy.android.ProjectChooser[1975]#0] disconnect: not connected (req=1)
2019-03-12 01:59:54.225 4326-7194/? E/BufferQueueProducer: [org.kivy.pygame/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity[2044]#0] disconnect: not connected (req=1)
2019-03-12 01:59:55.373 4870-5048/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '58b4637 org.kivy.pygame/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2019-03-12 02:08:30.817 13936-4463/? E/MTPJNIInterface: scanFile - /storage/emulated/0/kivy/MyApp/StudentProgress3.py
2019-03-12 02:08:41.348 13936-4704/? E/MTPJNIInterface: scanFile - /storage/emulated/0/kivy/MyApp/main.py
2019-03-12 02:08:48.766 13936-4708/? E/MTPJNIInterface: scanFile - /storage/emulated/0/kivy/MyApp/StudentProgress3.py
2019-03-12 02:08:48.779 13936-4708/? E/MTPJNIInterface: scanFile - /storage/emulated/0/kivy/MyApp/main.py
2019-03-12 02:08:53.422 4813-4813/? E/org.kivy.pygam: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2019-03-12 02:08:53.569 4813-4813/? E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/kivy/MyApp/icon.png (No such file or directory)
2019-03-12 02:08:53.873 4870-4983/? E/WindowManager: win=Window{9306df u0 Splash Screen org.kivy.pygame EXITING} destroySurfaces: appStopped=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=true win.mRemoveOnExit=true win.mViewVisibility=0 caller=com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:831 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:812 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onExitAnimationDone:5221 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.onAnimationFinished:315 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onAnimationFinished:5633 com.android.server.wm.-$$Lambda$yVRF8YoeNdTa8GR1wDStVsHu8xM.run:2 com.android.server.wm.SurfaceAnimator.lambda$getFinishedCallback$0:92 
2019-03-12 02:08:54.926 4326-4361/? E/BufferQueueProducer: [org.kivy.pygame/org.renpy.android.ProjectChooser[4813]#0] disconnect: not connected (req=1)
2019-03-12 02:08:55.012 4849-4849/? E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/kivy/MyApp/icon.png (No such file or directory)
2019-03-12 02:08:55.864 4326-5050/? E/BufferQueueProducer: [org.kivy.pygame/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity[4849]#0] disconnect: not connected (req=1)
2019-03-12 02:08:56.613 4870-5048/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '5d9bd33 org.kivy.pygame/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2019-03-12 02:20:58.509 7575-7575/? E/org.kivy.pygam: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2019-03-12 02:20:58.742 7575-7575/? E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/kivy/MyApp/icon.png (No such file or directory)
2019-03-12 02:20:59.101 4870-4983/? E/WindowManager: win=Window{40e033e u0 Splash Screen org.kivy.pygame EXITING} destroySurfaces: appStopped=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=true win.mRemoveOnExit=true win.mViewVisibility=0 caller=com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:831 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:812 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onExitAnimationDone:5221 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.onAnimationFinished:315 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onAnimationFinished:5633 com.android.server.wm.-$$Lambda$yVRF8YoeNdTa8GR1wDStVsHu8xM.run:2 com.android.server.wm.SurfaceAnimator.lambda$getFinishedCallback$0:92 
2019-03-12 02:21:01.207 4326-4361/? E/BufferQueueProducer: [org.kivy.pygame/org.renpy.android.ProjectChooser[7575]#0] disconnect: not connected (req=1)
2019-03-12 02:21:01.316 7619-7619/? E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/kivy/MyApp/icon.png (No such file or directory)
2019-03-12 02:21:02.264 4326-5050/? E/BufferQueueProducer: [org.kivy.pygame/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity[7619]#0] disconnect: not connected (req=1)
2019-03-12 02:21:03.009 4870-5048/? E/InputDispatcher: channel 'ce735e org.kivy.pygame/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

If anybody can help me it, I would be greatful. My code is below:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.app import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
#from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
#from kivy.uix.slider import Slider
import csv
import pickle

#empty_dict = {}                              # use this code if the pickle file is corrupt and needs to be reset.
#pickle_out = open("dict.pickle", "wb")
#pickle.dump(empty_dict, pickle_out)
#pickle_out.close()

class MainWindow(Screen):
    """This class will serve as the front page of the application.
    This input will be stored in a dictionary and later converted
    to a data structure using pandas and openpyxl."""

    # These variables link the python logic to the my2.kv kivy language file.
    first_name = ObjectProperty(None)
    last_name = ObjectProperty(None)
    level = ObjectProperty(None)

    # This section loads and saves the information stored from the user input.
    pickle_in = open('dict.pickle', 'rb')  # opens and assigns the opened pickle file to variable.
    student_data = pickle.load(pickle_in)  # imports the saved pickle file and assigns it to a variable.
    pickle_in.close()  # closes the pickle file for safety.

    def btn(self):
        #print(MainWindow.student_data)
        #print("First: " + self.first_name.text,
              #"Last: " + self.last_name.text)


        self.L = {self.first_name.text + ' ' + self.last_name.text: []}

        MainWindow.student_data.update(self.L)
        pickle_out = open("dict.pickle", "wb")
        pickle.dump(MainWindow.student_data, pickle_out)
        pickle_out.close()

        self.first_name.text = ''
        self.last_name.text = ''


class Controller(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Controller, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    def btn2(self):
        #print(self.lbl.text)
        #print(self.lbl2.text)
        #print(self.lbl3.text)
        #print(self.lbl4.text)
        #print(self.first_last.text)
        #print(self.first_last2.text)

        self.data = {self.first_last.text + ' ' + self.first_last2.text: [self.level.text, self.lbl.text, self.lbl2.text, self.lbl3.text, self.lbl4.text]}
        #print(self.data)

        # This section loads and saves the information stored from the user input.
        self.pickle_in = open('dict.pickle', 'rb')  # opens and assigns the opened pickle file to variable.
        self.loaded_data = pickle.load(self.pickle_in)  # imports the saved pickle file and assigns it to a variable.
        self.pickle_in.close()  # closes the pickle file for safety.

        #print(self.loaded_data)

        self.dictionary2 = self.data
        self.dictionary1 = self.loaded_data

        self.dictionary1.update(self.dictionary2)

        #print(self.dictionary1)

        pickle_out = open("dict.pickle", "wb")
        pickle.dump(self.dictionary1, pickle_out)
        pickle_out.close()

        self.first_last.text = ''
        self.first_last2.text = ''

    def Reading(self, *args):
        self.lbl.text = str(int(args[1]))

    def Dictation(self, *args):
        self.lbl2.text = str(int(args[1]))

    def Listening(self, *args):
        self.lbl3.text = str(int(args[1]))

    def Speaking(self, *args):
        self.lbl4.text = str(int(args[1]))




class ExporterScreen(Screen):
    def btn3(self):


        # This section loads and saves the information stored from the user input.
        self.pickle_in = open('dict.pickle', 'rb')  # opens and assigns the opened pickle file to variable.
        self.dict = pickle.load(self.pickle_in)  # imports the saved pickle file and assigns it to a variable.
        self.pickle_in.close()  # closes the pickle file for safety.

        #print(self.dict)

        temporary_row = []
        rows_list = []

        for k, v in self.dict.items():
            temporary_row.append(k)
            for i in v:
                temporary_row.append(i)
            rows_list.append(temporary_row)
            temporary_row = []

        with open('student_data.csv', 'w') as csvFile:

            writer = csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter=',')

            writer.writerow(['NAME', 'LEVEL', 'READING', 'DICTATION', 'WRITING', 'SPEAKING'])
            writer.writerows(rows_list) #the row should be ex: James, Earth, 23, 34, 45, 63

        csvFile.close()


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


kv = Builder.load_file("my2.kv")


class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

Here is my .kv code:

```
WindowManager:
    MainWindow:
    Controller:
    ExporterScreen:


<MainWindow>:
    name: "main"
    first_name: first
    last_name: last


    GridLayout
        cols: 1
        size: root.width, root.height


        GridLayout:
            cols: 2

            Label:
                text: "Student First Name: "
            TextInput:
                id: first
                multiline: False

            Label:
                text: "Student Last Name: "
            TextInput:
                id: last
                multiline: False

        Button:
            size_hint: 0.3, 0.2
            text: "Submit"
            on_press: root.btn()

        FloatLayout:
            Button:
                font_size: 25
                size_hint: 0.3, 0.2
                text: ">"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "second"
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
                pos_hint: {"right":1, "bottom": 1}

            Button:
                font_size: 25
                size_hint: 0.3, 0.2
                text: "<"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "third"
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
                pos_hint: {"left":1, "bottom": 1}


<Controller>
    name: "second"
    lbl: my_label
    lbl2: my_label2
    lbl3: my_label3
    lbl4: my_label4
    first_last: first_last
    first_last2: first_last2
    level: level

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            font_size: 25
            text: 'Reading'
        Label:
            id: my_label
            text: 'increase/decrease'
        Slider:
            min: 1
            max: 100
            on_value: root.Reading(*args)
        Label:
            font_size: 25
            text: 'Dictation'
        Label:
            id: my_label2
            text: 'increase/decrease'
        Slider:
            min: 1
            max: 100
            on_value: root.Dictation(*args)
        Label:
            font_size: 25
            text: 'Writing'
        Label:
            id: my_label3
            text: 'increase/decrease'
        Slider:
            min: 1
            max: 100
            on_value: root.Listening(*args)
        Label:
            font_size: 25
            text: 'Speaking'
        Label:
            id: my_label4
            text: 'increase/decrease'
        Slider:
            min: 1
            max: 100
            on_value: root.Speaking(*args)
        Label:
            text: "Level (Sky^, Sky, Earth, Rockets)"
        TextInput:
            multiline: False
            id: level

        GridLayout:
            cols:2
            Label:
                text: "First Name"
            TextInput:
                font_size: 8
                id: first_last
                multiline: False
            Label:
                text: "Last Name"
            TextInput:
                font_size: 8
                id: first_last2
                multiline: False


        GridLayout:
            cols: 3
            Button:
                text: "<"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "main"
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
            Button:
                text: "Update"
                on_press: root.btn2()
            Button:
                text: ">"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "third"
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "left"


<ExporterScreen>
    name: "third"
    #GridLayout:
    #    orientation: "vertical"
#
    #    Button:
    #        font_size: 25
    #        size_hint: 0.3, 0.2
    #        text: "Export Data"
    #        on_press: root.btn3()
#
#
    #    FloatLayout:
    #        cols: 3
    #        Button:
    #            size_hint: 0.3, 0.2
    #            text: "<"
    #            on_release:
    #                app.root.current = "second"
    #                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
    #            pos_hint: {"left": 1, "bottom": 1}
    #        #Button:
#
    #        Button:
    #            size_hint: 0.3, 0.2
    #            text: ">"
    #            on_release:
    #                app.root.current = "main"
    #                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
    #            pos_hint: {"right":1, "bottom": 1}

    PageLayout:
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            cols: 3
            Label:
                text: "Hi"
            Label:
                text: "This application is still in developement"

            Label:
                text: "Bye"

            Button:
                font_size: 25
                #size_hint: 0.3, 0.2
                text: "Export Data"
                on_press: root.btn3()
        Label:
            text: 'This is just a blank page :('


        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            cols: 3
            Label:
                text: ":)"
            Label:
                text: "Hello"

            Label:
                text: ":("

            Button:
                text: "Home"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "main"
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
```